# Can you stop Chrome using https screenshots on the new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

Can you stop Chrome from showing screenshots of https sites on the new tab page? (or even specific sites)

I'd rather it didn't show a thumbnail of my online banking complete with account numbers and balances. It may not be readable but it is an unnecessary security risk.

Comment: What about simply deleting the entry from the list?

Comment: @Synetech does that permanently stop a site from appearing in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38256) was raised in Chrome (thanks to @Synetech for the link) regarding this but has now been marked as won't fix.

In [comment 12](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38256#c12) of the issue it was confirmed that using the x in the upper right of the thumbnail to remove it blacklists that page from appearing in most visited.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been brought up as an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38256) more than two years ago, but not only has it not been addressed, there is actually *resistance* to the idea of dealing with it.

Since it doesn’t look like it will be fixed in the foreseeable future, you can work around it by deleting the `thumbnails` file from your Chrome [user-data-directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). If you use any sort of scheduled file-cleaning program, you can add it to the list to be automatically wiped.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue. I did a search before I posted the question as I expected that it would have been raised before but couldn't fine anything. I did see that Firefox had the same issue when they introduced this feature but seem to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to manually edit it from the Chrome Preferences file located in your AppData file, but that doesn't appear to be possible now.

Your best bet is to use an extension that allows for customisation of the 'new tab' interface, like [Speed Dial](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi?hl=en-gb).